# Slow double left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have the following query that performs left join between 3 tables. The problem is that it takes 20 seconds to run, even if only few rows are returned. If I leave out the "largefields" from the offer table the query executes almost instantly. So it appears that the problem is that for some reason the sqlserver fetches the values of those fields before it applies the where statement. Is there any way to make this query execute faster?

```
SELECT N0."OID"
    ,N1."FirstName"
    ,N1."LastName"
    ,N0."SmallField"
    ,N0."LargeField1"
    ,N0."LargeField2"
FROM (
    (
        "dbo"."Offer" N0 LEFT JOIN "dbo"."Address" N1 ON (N0."OfferDeliveryAddress" = N1."OID")
        ) LEFT JOIN "dbo"."Customer" N2 ON (N0."Customer" = N2."OID")
    )
WHERE (
        N0."GCRecord" IS NULL
        AND (
            (isnull(CharIndex('John Smith', N2."FirstName" + ' ' + N2."LastName"), 0) > 0)
            OR (isnull(CharIndex('John Smith', N2."LastName" + ' ' + N2."FirstName"), 0) > 0)
            OR (isnull(CharIndex('John Smith', N2."FirstName"), 0) > 0)
            OR (isnull(CharIndex('John Smith', N2."LastName"), 0) > 0)
            )
        )
```

Comment: Probably it is slow not because of joins, but your complicated where clause

Comment: Could you create a sql-fiddle, it will give people means of looking at "sample" data, an execution plan, and be able to provide solutions

Comment: Change the LEFT JOIN on Customer to an INNER JOIN, your WHERE CLAUSE would exclude any that don't have a record in Customer anyway. Try this as your where condition: CharIndex('John Smith', COALESCE([N2].[FirstName], '') + ' ' + COALESCE([2].[lastName], '')) > 0

Answer (score 1):

At least you can optimize your where condition as follow:

```
WHERE (
        N0."GCRecord" IS NULL
        AND (
            (isnull(CharIndex('John Smith', N2."FirstName" + ' ' + N2."LastName"), 0) > 0)
            OR (isnull(CharIndex('John Smith', N2."LastName" + ' ' + N2."FirstName"), 0) > 0)
            )
        )
```

because the last two conditions are included in the first two.

**Edited**
As an example to see why this is true:

```
FirstName = 'XXXJohn Smith'
LastName = 'YYY'

FirstName + ' ' + LastName = 'XXXJohnSmith YYY'
```

so if *JohnSmith* is contained in `FirstName` it is also contained in `FirstName + ' ' + LastName`

Comment: `because the last two conditions are included in the first two`. This is incorrect. In last two conditions he is searching for John Smith in FirstName only or LastName only.

Comment: But if John Smith is included in FirstName is also included in FirstName + ' ' + LastName and same for LastName + ' ' + FirstName. As an example if FirstName is 'XXXJohn SmithXXX' and lastName is 'YYY' so FirstName + ' ' + LastName is 'XXXJohn SmithXXX YYY' and it contains as obviously 'John Smith'

Comment: yes you are correct. sorry for that. taking back my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `WHERE` clause to sargable clause:

```
WHERE (
        N0."GCRecord" IS NULL
        AND (
               (N2."FirstName" LIKE 'John%' AND N2."LastName" LIKE 'Smith%') OR 
               (N2."LastName" LIKE 'John%' AND N2."FirstName" LIKE 'Smith%') OR 
                N2."FirstName" LIKE 'John Smith%' OR 
                N2."LastName" LIKE 'John Smith%' 
            )
        )
```

Add indexes to column `FirstName` and `LastName`.
This where clause should benefit from those indexes, because `LIKE 'ABC%'` is sargable.

Comment: This is not equivalent to what is asked. Here you search FirstName starting with John. He asked for FirstName containing John... and so on.

Comment: You have at least to modify it to the following equivalent WHERE (
        N0."GCRecord" IS NULL
        AND (
               (N2."FirstName" LIKE '%John%' AND N2."LastName" LIKE 'Smith%') OR 
               (N2."LastName" LIKE '%John%' AND N2."FirstName" LIKE 'Smith%') OR 
                N2."FirstName" LIKE '%John Smith%' OR 
                N2."LastName" LIKE '%John Smith%' 
            )
        )

Comment: Yes, but this answer is focusing on optimizing through SARGs. Other way it will not use any indexes. So if this statement satisfy data in database then it will be better to stick to this statement. `LIKE '%ABC%'` will not use index. `LIKE 'ABC%'` will use index. That is the point.

Comment: How do you know the result is wrong. If this statement is acceptable, then it will use index and so OP`s statement will be optimized. Of course if there is data like 'XYZJojn' in table then it will not work, but why on earth data may contain such rows?

Comment: Why on Earth would one search for `John` as the last name and `Smith` as the first name? Why on Earth would both names be stored only as either the first name or the last name? And yet the OP *is* checking those cases. So their data may already be inconsistent. Yes, `'XYZJohn'` may be somewhat extreme, but it could be `'  John'` (i.e. with spaces at the beginning), which is not too improbable to find in corrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

- First in the select part, removing N0."LargeField1", N."LargeField2" make a difference?
- 2nd, in where part N2."FirstName" and  N2."LastName" is potentially in trouble because querying on function didn't use the database index
- And please check your execution plan.